# How to produce a grand piano sound on AudioKit 4.1 for iOS?

Tags: swift4, audiokit

I am playing around with the AudioKit 4.1 framework of Swift and after reading a bit about it, I found that there are a lot of settings available to produce different sounds using the oscillator. What particular settings should I tweak using the AKOscillator class to produce a grand piano sound?

Comment: Well then is there a way to produce a piano sound given different parameters like the type of note (whole, half, quarter), and the accidentals like sharps in any way using AudioKit 4.1?

Comment: Did you figure out how to play piano notes using the repo referenced by analog code below? I would like to do that.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to implement a realistic grand piano sound using AudioKit is to create an AKSampler based instrument. There is a robust code example in the AudioKit "ROM Player" repo which documents techniques and tips for making sampled based instruments such as pianos.

https://github.com/AudioKit/ROMPlayer

[image: RomPlayer]